# Sql server results returning duplicates and distinct and other things are not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, distinct

I have a table that contains a foreign key DOCCCOIssuesId of which this column has the same value multiple times.  Now what ends up making the record unique is that this other column AcceptedByNTID is not null.

Some reason I have some duplicate entries in which that is causing the problem.  (Yes, eventually that needs to be addressed to ensure unique rows)
For now I have results

```
DOCCCOIssuesId      AcceptedByNTID 
   1                  abc
   14                 def
   14                 hij
   15                 abc
   16                 def
   16                 abc
```

So I only want to select records that have a value in AcceptedByNTID but I just want to grab a distinct DOCCCOIssuesId  and NOT have > 1 of any given DOCCCOIssuesId

```
select 
     DOCCCOIssuesId
    ,AcceptedByNTID 
FROM 
    [ESO].[ESO].[DOCCCOIssuesResponse] dir
where  
     dir.AcceptedByNTID IS NOT NULL
```

I was trying distinct, subquery, group by, having,  max  ,  just not figuring it out.

**results i would want**

```
DOCCCOIssuesId      AcceptedByNTID 
   1                  abc
   14                 def
   15                 abc
   16                 def
```

Comment: You need to specify the criteria which `AcceptedByNTID`  value you want when there is more than one `DOCCCOIssuesId` As an example, for DOCCCOIssuesId `14`, how do you know that you want `def` and not `hij`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group your `DOCCCOIssuesId` and get the `MIN` of it.

```
SELECT MIN(DOCCCOIssuesId)
       , AcceptedByNTID
FROM [ESO].[ESO].[DOCCCOIssuesResponse] dir
WHERE dir.AcceptedByNTID IS NOT NULL GROUP BY DOCCCOIssuesId, AcceptedByNTID
```

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'ESO.ESO.DOCCCOIssuesResponse.AcceptedByNTID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: SELECT MIN(DOCCCOIssuesId)
       , AcceptedByNTID
FROM [ESO].[ESO].[DOCCCOIssuesResponse] dir
WHERE dir.AcceptedByNTID IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY DOCCCOIssuesId,AcceptedByNTID

Comment: I don't understand why the OP answer ran with error  but his only gave 3 records back,   yours did not run, but the error message made it easy to just add in the other column into the group by aggregate.   Thus someone between your answer and his,  I didn't realize that the ordering of the group by was so important  GROUP BY DOCCCOIssuesId,AcceptedByNTID       that does indeed give the 24 records I want    .

Comment: @BrianThornton sorry i forgot to include `AcceptedByNTID` in group by :) all columns in the `select` must be in `group by` , but if we use aggregate function, we can exclude that. :) answer edited adding the `AcceptedByNTID` in group by.

Comment: GROUP BY DOCCCOIssuesId, AcceptedByNTID    works    but this does not    GROUP BY AcceptedByNTID, DOCCCOIssuesId      So the order of the group by is important?

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by`:

```
select MIN(DOCCCOIssuesId), AcceptedByNTID 
from [ESO].[ESO].[DOCCCOIssuesResponse] dir
where dir.AcceptedByNTID IS NOT NULL
group by AcceptedByNTID;
```

The `min()` (or `max()`) is an arbitrary value for that column.

EDIT:

I misunderstood the question.  You seem to just want `select distinct`:

```
select distinct DOCCCOIssuesId, AcceptedByNTID 
from [ESO].[ESO].[DOCCCOIssuesResponse] dir
where dir.AcceptedByNTID IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I only get 3 records with that query.   I am guessing that it is hard to know it without you seeing the data   I need to probably use sqlfiddle

Comment: I had to go with the OP answer ,  so I gather that I needed to group by other column first , I'm slightly confused but I guess that the ordering of the group by is important       GROUP BY DOCCCOIssuesId,AcceptedByNTID